# Remove option in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select class="one">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="one">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="one">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

$(".one").change(function(){

})
```

I would like make - for example if i select in first position option 1 then i others selects this option should be removed.
So if i in first select i select 1 then in select second and third i have only option 2 and 3. If in second select i select 2 then in last select i have only option 3.

How can i make it? I would like use jQuery.

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/9N9Tz/1/

Comment: I have three position, i must order this, so if i selected one option then in others select this option should be removed - this option is in first select

Comment: I don't think pulldowns are the best interface for this. Depending on how much work you are willing to do, why not put up little boxes labeled 1-2-3 and have the user drag them into the order she wants?

Comment: @gdoron - What, posting it as a question on SO doesn't count as effort?

Comment: @JaredFarrish. Of course it does... +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to sort something, consider using something like [jQuery UI sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable) as a bunch of drop down menus make a really poor UX for that.

But to answer your question:

```js
var $selects = $('.one');
$selects.on("keyup click change", function(e) {
  $selects.not(this).trigger('updateselection');
}).on("updateselection", function(e, data) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.children().show();
  $selects.not(this).each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value) {
      $this.children('[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="one">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="one">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="one">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Hiding an option works in current firefox. I'm not sure about legacy browser. Hiding, but not removing, the element makes sure that you can change your selection without having crippled your input elements.

Comment: Finally not a "add an id" answer.

Comment: @JaredFarrish what would one need an ID for in this case? little confused by your comment :/

Comment: Your answer was the first to *not* suggest "just add an id or more classes". In other words, you were actually using jQuery's DOM traversal methods. So no, you don't need an id. *Of course.*

Comment: IE does not support hide/show of options in some, if not all versions so although solution looks simple it is not cross browser compatible

Answer (score 3):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/9N9Tz/6/.

When the value of the `<select>`s changes, just take this value and search for the `<option>`s with this value in the others `<select>`s and remove them.

```
$(".one").change(function(){
    var val = this.value
    if (val !== '') {
        $(this).siblings().find('option[value=' + val + ']').remove()
    }
})
```

Comment: I would have used `$.siblings()`. Please post your code in the answer, too.

Comment: That's one of my first post, thanks for the advice, I'll do it now.

Comment: The only problem I can see with this is that once the selects are removed, they're gone. So modifying a selection could lead to trouble.

Comment: I find that a bit weird too but that's what @paul-jeggor ask for. I've made a [little example](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/9N9Tz/15/) with a reset button to show the hidden `<option>`s  
EDIT: ok, no code in comments :(

Answer (score 1):

It will be easy if you use different class for second and third select element

```
$(".one").change(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    $('.two,.three').find('option:contains('+val+')').remove();  
});
```

EDIT:
Updated code to apply for multiple selects. [Thanks to all commentators and Alex for bringing it to notice ]

```
  $(".one").change(function(){
        var val = parseInt($(this).val());
        $(this).siblings().find('option:contains('+val+')').remove();  
    });
```

Comment: @PaulJeggor: I think you skipped first line from my answer. 
Check this WORKING version as per my answer http://jsfiddle.net/9N9Tz/11/.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble: I will appreciate some details.

Comment: @Ajinkya : I am not the downvoter .. but I think you need to read the question once again.  He wants it to be implemented for the second select after the first.  So u have to write a lot of code if there are multiple selects.. check the answer of Alex

Comment: You don't need to add classes/id attributes for this to work in jQuery. That's why there's DOM methods like `$.siblings()` and whatnot, so you can traverse without too much specification. `.one`, `.two` and `.three` are not great class names, either, as they don't imply or depict meaning or groupings.

Comment: @nandu:Thanks. I misunderstood the question. Have updated the answer.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thanks for comment. I thought OP wants to remove option from only 2 particular select elements. If page contains other select then my suggestion will be good option. And I used `.two`,`,three` just to illustrate the answer.

Comment: id's should be used for specificity of assignment, classes for belonging to groups or having characteristics. The intent in the suggestion is that the class names imply differentiation, which is indicative of id's, not classes. So, by form, they would all need to belong to the same group semantically. jQuery allows you to manage the rest here in most cases without needing id attributes, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
// As soon as all selects have one class, you'll have to distinguish them:
$(".one").each(function() { 
    // Now this corresponds to one select (in the loop over all)
    $(this).change(function() {
       // Fix what've done before
       $('option').show();
       // Find every other select, find an option in it
       // that has the same value that is selected in current select
       // (sorry for the description)
       $('.one').not(this).find('option[value=' + $(this).find('option:selected').val() +']').hide();
    });
})​;​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9N9Tz/1/)

Comment: just a small question in your answer. Y did you use .hide() and not .remove()??  Any particular reason??

Comment: because after you remove the element, there is no easy way to go back. As OP said, choosing 1, 2, 3 in series should not just delete all options.