# dynamic drop down lists

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dynamic, html-select

**SOLUTION**: [Remove option in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071562/remove-option-in-select)

I have a form where I would like users to rank their 'Top 3' from a list of 10 choices.

To validate responses I'd like a drop down next to each of the ten items.  With the choices 1 to 3 - however, when a users selects '1' from anyone of the choices, all the drop downs get updated to show only options 2 and 3.

Similarly, when a users chooses option 3 for any one of the ten, the remaining drop downs are updated to only show option 2 and when that is selected all remaining drop downs are updated to show nothing or disabled.

I've used dynamic drop downs in the past via Javascript but not to this level of complexity - any thoughts or ideas, code examples or alternatives (Ajax etc.) welcomed!

Thanks,

H.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I have no idea where to start with this one - a jFiddle example won't help.  Apologies but the description is as simple as it gets!

Comment: Take a look at [stackoverflow.com/questions/11071562/remove-option-in-select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071562/remove-option-in-select). Looks very similar

Comment: Sean, add that as answer and I'll accept and tick it!!! - Thank you.  Why couldn't I find that before I posted my response! DOH!

Comment: Also does it have to be a dropdown? It could be easily done with radio groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try - [stackoverflow.com/questions/11071562/remove-option-in-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071562/remove-option-in-select).

Also you could try radio groups-

```
<input type="radio" name="first" value="choice1">
<input type="radio" name="second" value="choice1">
<input type="radio" name="third" value="choice1">

<input type="radio" name="first" value="choice2">
<input type="radio" name="second" value="choice2">
<input type="radio" name="third" value="choice2">

....
```