# Javascript solution for hiding dropdown list options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Edit:
Thanks everybody, but nothing seems to work. I am inserting this code in a file that I know is being used and that contains other javascript blocks normally formatted, and this still doesn't work. It works in a fiddle, but not on my code. I guess this is too specific to the platform and extension that I'm trying to modify (this is part of a Magento checkout step modified by a third party extension). I will start looking into replacing the list with a manually generated one. Thanks again.

---

I am trying to hide an option in a dropdown list that is dinamically generated. The CSS solution doesn't work on all browsers, and even though I have found several similar questions here, neither one offers a solution that works for me.

Here's what my list renders like:

```
<select id="timeselect" name="adj[delivery_time][]" title="El plazo de la entrega" class="adjtimeselect select" type="time" ><option id="option-10" value="10" >10</option>
<option id="option-11" value="11" >11</option>
<option id="option-12" value="12" >12</option>
<option id="option-13" value="13" >13</option>
<option id="option-14" value="14" >14</option>
<option id="option-15" value="15" >15</option>
<option id="option-16" value="16" >16</option>
<option id="option-17" value="17" >17</option>
<option id="option-18" value="18" >18</option>
<option id="option-19" value="19" >19</option>
<option id="option-20" value="20" >20</option>
</select>
```

I need to hide the option with value "12" for example.
I am using this JS:

```
$("#timeselect option[value='12']").remove();
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated since I'm new to JS.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `$("#timeselect option[value='12']").hide()`. For further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071562/remove-option-in-select

Comment: .remove() is the right function you are using... whats problem in it.. you just want to hide not to remove???

Comment: Note that $ indicates jQuery, so you need to include that before your script.

Comment: @maverickosama92 I can do with either hide or remove, I just need it to be impossible to select via any possible method, but either way nothing happens, the option is still there.

Comment: Then you're probably missing something... Maybe the jQuery include like people said here. Please upload your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can take a look

Comment: thanks @JensNeubauer, this is what I'm using:
 `<script type="text/javascript">
$("#timeselect option[value='12']").hide();
</script>`

Comment: @PalmerDelCampo: Put `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` right before that.

Comment: @PalmerDelCampo: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zApq4/9/

Comment: @maverickosama92 Thanks, I tried checked that fiddle and it works, but it doesn't work on my file. Including jQuery before the script block doesn't work for me either. This code is part of a magento checkout step, and adding jQuery  disables all checkout steps. Maybe it won't be so simple after all.

Comment: Then jQuery is probably already included in the page. Where is your JS code on the page? Either move it all the way to the end of the body tag, or wrap it in a ready-event: `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){$("#timeselect option[value='12']").hide();}); </script>`

Comment: thanks @JensNeubauer, I have found the following link that details how to insert JS in magento checkout steps. Could you help me fit your code into this structure?
[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/53872/)

Comment: Well, try this then: `<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#timeselect option[value='12']").hide();
  });
</script>`

Comment: Thanks everybody, but nothing seems to work. I am inserting this code in a file that I know is being used and that contains other javascript blocks normally formatted, and this still doesn't work. It works in a fiddle, but not on my code. I guess this is too specific to the platform and extension that I'm trying to modify. I will start looking into replacing the list with a manually generated one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `hide()` function of JQuery: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTWcM/)

You can use `show()` to get it back

Answer (score 3):

Jquery remove by value

```
$("#timeselect option[value=11]").remove();
```

Jquery remove by Text

```
$("#timeselect option:contains(11)").remove();
```

`Jquery` to hide a select box option with its value using css

```
   $("#timeselect option[value='11']").hide();
```

or

```
   $("#timeselect option[value='11']").css('display','none');
```

Comment: @PalmerDelCampo : does this answers your question dude?

Comment: `hide()` works perfectly for me. haven't tried other options though

Answer (score 2):

I tried in many different ways but this solution seems reasonable and cross browser compatible and I have used in my code. No plugins required simple register function with jquery object

Solution at glance:

```
(function ($) {


$('#showOne').click(function () {
    $('#ddlNumbers').showHideDropdownOptions('3', true);
});

$('#hideOne').click(function () {
    $('#ddlNumbers').showHideDropdownOptions('3', false);
});

 $.fn.showHideDropdownOptions = function(value, canShowOption) { 

         $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').map(function () {
            return $(this).parent('span').length === 0 ? this : null;
        }).wrap('<span>').hide();

        if (canShowOption) 
            $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').unwrap().show();
        else 
            $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();

}



})(jQuery);
```

Here is the complete implementation http://jsfiddle.net/8uxD7/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery remove() function. if you want to remove it permanently from DOM, or if you want to remove and reinsert it use detach()

```
$("#timeselect option[value='12']").remove();
```

Or Detach

```
var value = $("#timeselect option[value='12']").detach();
```

And reinsert it by using

```
$("#timeselect").append(value);
```

http://jsbin.com/iHIrAQE/5/edit

See the example

Another way is you can disable the value so user can see but cannot select

```
$("#timeselect option[value='12']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```